# jQuery noob: (this).replacewith am I doing it wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I've been learning more and more about jQuery but here I've become stuck.

I have a code to change the color of a div when a checkbox is cliked, that works fine.

After this I want to be able to change the contents of a textarea on focus, I tried this:

```
    //textarea
    $("textarea").focus(function(){
        if ($(this).contains('Skriv valg av headset her')){
         $(this).replaceWith('');
    });
```

But there is no effect. Do I have some syntax errors or am I taking the wrong approach?

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/HLBGA/1/).

Comment: HTML5 inputs and textareas have a `placeholder` attribute. If you're ready to give up having this text on older browsers, it would solve your problem.

Comment: @3nigma The statement is a link, it brings to http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/HLBGA/1/

Comment: @ zneak-- earlier it didn't show as a link at my end v-strange

Comment: @zneak: I really wish I could make the jump to HTML5, but I am working with a pre-built solution, reworking everything to HTML5 would be a huge undertaking. Maybe in a year or so :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure browsers that support HTML5 will gladly display the placeholder, even if the document is not declared as HTML5. I'd be surprised if you had to change anything else. Well, might be worth trying :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`$.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) function and the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, but no `jQuery.fn.contains`. You're looking for [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) here I believe:

```
$('textarea').focus(function(){
    var t = $(this);

    if(t.val().indexOf('Skriv valg av headset her') !== -1) {
        t.val('');
    }
});
```

`replaceWith` is also wrong here - *if* that were to work (and it shouldn't I believe because it takes either a DOM element or a HTML text) it would remove the `textarea` element (which is better done with `remove` anyway)

Comment: Great, thanks :) I guess I really was going about it the wrong way. Not sure I understand how this works, I shall learn it :D

Comment: +1 the 'replacewith' (if you had the .contains syntax right) would have quite cheerfully wiped out your textbox and replaced it with an empty string in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//textarea
$("textarea").focus(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // Always cache your selector

    if ($this.contains('Skriv valg av headset her'))
    {
        $this.val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, plus side is at least jslint validates the code now :)

Comment: Definitely check out the first example posted. They are using indexOf which should work.